# Where does setup.py get the version from in pytest?

Tags: python, pip, pypi

I'm currently learning about distribution packaging in Python, and while doing so looking at some familiar projects and how they do it.

So I was looking at the source tree of `pytest`,  and I can't figure out how is the version read by running `setup.py --version`, and also by tools like pip, etc.

Basically, there is the file `src/_pytest/_version.py` which contains:

```
__version__ = version = '7.2.0.dev228+g58cf20edf'
__version_tuple__ = version_tuple = (7, 2, 0, 'dev228', 'g58cf20edf')
```

Then, the `__init__.py` file imports these variables:

```
__all__ = ["__version__", "version_tuple"]

try:
    from ._version import version as __version__, version_tuple
```

But the `setup.py` and `setup.cfg` both don't have a `version=` field, so I can't understand how this information is read by setuptools when I run:

```
$ py setup.py --version
```

?